# Return CLLocationCoordinate2D to struct

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, clgeocoder, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm new in programming and my question is how to return data of variables type CLLocationCoordinate2D to Coordinates i.e. type of a structure. Trying to develop a weather app.

I have a struct:

```
struct Coordinates {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

My code looks as follows:

```
//getting coordinates from String
func getCoordinateFrom(address: String, completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
                CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
                    completion(placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error)
                }
            }

//When the User type his city, coordinates have type of CLLocationCoordinate2D    
@IBAction func changeCityButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            guard let address = textField.text else { return }
            getCoordinateFrom(address: address) { coordinate, error in
                guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(coordinate)
                }  
            }
        }
```

I've got a constant and **my task is to transfer coordinates** from function to this constant.

```
  let coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: 00.617366, longitude: 37.617366)
```

The problem is that these coordinates in function are in closure. So I can't return them or etc. I try to find the right answer but with no results. Anybody have some advice/solution?

Comment: from where do you want to return coordinates

Comment: from 'let coordinate' which located in func changeCityButtonPressed. It have latitude & longitude of the city

Comment: where is your variable where you want to store the coordinates

Comment: @Over pls explain perfect nobody can understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on this line:

```
 let coordinates = Coordinates(latitude: 00.617366, longitude: 37.617366)
```

replace `let` with `var`

and in this code:

```
  @IBAction func changeCityButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let address = textField.text else { return }
        getCoordinateFrom(address: address) { coordinate, error in
            guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(coordinate)
            }  
        }
    }
```

replace this:

```
  guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(coordinate)
            }
```

by this:

```
  guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
            coordinates.latitude = coordinate.latitude
            coordinates.longitude = coordinate.longitude
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(coordinate)
            }
```

this is how your coordinates variable will be updated with new lat long

Comment: It helped to sort out your issue?

Comment: almost. thank you! your code + ".self" helps me: `guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
            self.coordinates.latitude = coordinate.latitude
            self.coordinates.longitude = coordinate.longitude`

Comment: ohhh hahahaha I forgot `self`